# The sum of $1/(ci-1)$ from $i=n\alpha$ to $n-1$

Tags: integration, summation

For fixed $c>0$ and $\alpha \in (0,1)$, find the sum (as $n \to \infty$) of:
$$ \sum_{i=n\alpha}^{n-1} \frac{1}{ci-1} $$
This looks like a harmonic sum which doesn't converge, but the fact that it starts from $n\alpha$ causes me to suspect that, as $n \to \infty$,
$$ \sum_{i=n\alpha}^{n-1} \frac{1}{ci-1} \;\to\; \frac{\log(1/\alpha)}{c}$$
I finagled this by a Riemann integral approximation, but I didn't deal with the $-1$ factor in the denominator rigorously. Is there a simpler way to do this?

Comment: Is that j supposed to be an i?

Comment: @ChristopherHalverson oops, you are correct. fixed. thanks!